# Why is element checking handled differently between list and set?

Tags: python, list, set

Why is element checking handled differently between a list and a set?

Let me give the following example:

`'a' in ['aa']` returns `False`

`'a' in ('aa')` returns `True`

Comment: `('aa')` is a string in parenthesis, It's neither a set nor a tuple. So the character `a` *is` present in `'aa'`

Comment: `('aa') == 'aa'` you need to use `('aa',)` for single element tuple.

Comment: Single element tuples should have a comma at the end. For example, `('aa',)` or simply `'aa',`

Comment: {'aa'} is a set, ('aa') is a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `('aa')` you are simply creating a string, so it is obvious that `in` will check characters and evaluate as `True`. You can verify this with

```
>>> x = ('aa')
>>> print(type(x))
<class 'str'>
```

As seen in the docs [tuple syntax](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TupleSyntax), in order to create a single element tuple you require a trailing comma, i.e. `('aa',)`.  In this case, checking for `'a'` inside your tuple will result in `False` as expected.

If you *actually* create a set with

```
x = set('aa')
```

which is what I imagine you did, a set is created with the unique characters inside your string as elements, since your passed string is seen as an iterable for the set to get elements from (*characters*). Hence, your set becomes `{'a'}`, so `in` will evaluate as `True`. On the contrary, if you create a set with set literal syntax

```
x = {'aa'}
```

a set is created with your single string `'aa'`, and `in` will evaluate as `False`. So it depends on how you initialize a set from `'aa'`.

```
>>> set('dog')
{'d', 'g', 'o'}
>>> {'dog'}
{'dog'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `('aa')` isn't a tuple it's string. Tuple creation operator is `,`.
So in your use case  command `'a' in ('aa')` actually checks weather 'a' char present in 'aa' string what is true.

Equivalent operation with tuple would be `'a' in ('aa',)` which is falsy.

See more info on [python doc#tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#tuple) and [implicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).